# How to continue a Time Machine restore when/after getting an "Error (-5000)" message

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore, macos

I try to restore via `tmutil` a backup snapshot from my Time Machine disk to a new volume. For this I issue:

```
sudo tmutil restore /Volumes/MyTMDisk/Backups.backupdb/MyMachine/2021-11-30-042315/MyHD') /Volumes/MySnapshot
```

After a day or so I get the following error:

> Error (-5000) (SrcErr:NO) Copying '/Volumes/MyTMDisk/Backups.backupdb/MyMachine/2021-11-30-042315/MyHD/Users/myself/Library/Application Support/NeoFinder/SmartFolders/All Items with Thumbnails.query' to '/Volumes/MySnapshot/`/Users/myself/Library/Application Support/NeoFinder/SmartFolders'

And then `tmutil` exits. Upon investigation of the destination volume I can see that `tmutil` copied lots of stuff, but it seems after it reached the error in the `SmartFolders` directory, `tmutil` stalled.

Is there a way to instruct `tmutil` to continue restoring after reaching the error? Or can I tell `tmutil` to omit the problematic directory during the restore?

---

PS: I am running Catalina 10.15.7